# What is lighttpd's version of mod_ruby?

Tags: web-server, lighttpd, ruby

I'm trying to find a mod_ruby for lighttpd, not apache2. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ruby is used through FastCGI with LigHTTPd.

For building on OSX Tiger: [this guide](http://hivelogic.com/articles/ruby_rails_lighttpd_mysql_tiger)
From the ArchLinux wiki: [this wiki](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fastcgi_and_lighttpd)

Personally, I have found many build-on-osx guides to be minimally adapted to work on other *nixes.

Comment: its not a very good page for describing how to configure fastcgi...

Comment: What is your OS? Please look for a tutorial or guide specific to your OS.

Comment: Added two links which look to be more readable than the last one.

Answer (score 1):

For performance i suggest you running http://www.modrails.com/ with nginx and ruby enterprise.

With lighttpd you are left with FastCGI or mongrels .

Comment: I'm not trying to build a rails app, just needed a ruby interpreter on a webserver.